# How to show a correspondence is lower-hemicontinous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, closed-graph, set-valued-analysis

I have a composite function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, such that $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n,Y\subset\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, where $f$ involves a combination of transformations:

1. Form a finite number $p$ of matrix polynomials in $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$. Call them $A_1,\dots,A_p$.
2. The matrices $A_1,\dots,A_p$ form another polynomial in $z\in \mathbb{C}$, i.e., $A_1 z^{-q}+A_2 z^{-q+1}+\cdots+A_p z^r=0$
3. Apply QZ decomposition to $A_1$ (or simply a Wiener Hopf factorization of the whole polynomial)
4. Perform $[\cdot]_+$ to one of the factorized matrices to get rid of the negative order terms in $z$.
5. Perform matrix addition, multiplication and inversion of the resulting matrices.

Now I would like to show (if possible) $f^{-1}$ is in fact a continuous correspondence **at a generic point**, or almost everywhere.

Since I have a bounded space, and $f$ is continuous (can show it is analytic bc Wiener-Hopf preserves analyticity), proving upper-hemicontinuity should not be a problem.

My question is, how do I proceed to show its lower-hemicontinuity **at a certain point**? If not, what conditions are needed?

It looks like if $f$ is defined on complex domain, by open mapping theorem and the fact any open mapping $f$ its inverse correspondence is lower-hemicontinuous we are done here. But the problem is $X$ is a Euclidean space. Not sure if this is ok.

Thank you!

Here's a definition of lower- hemicontinuity from Efe A.Ok *Real Analysis with Economic Applications*  (2007)

> Proposition 4. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two metric spaces, and $\Gamma: X \rightrightarrows Y$ a correspondence. $\Gamma$ is lower hemicontinuous at $x \in X$ if, and only if, for any $\left(x^{m}\right) \in X^{\infty}$ with $x^{m} \rightarrow x$ and any $y \in \Gamma(x)$, there exists a $\left(y^{m}\right) \in Y^{\infty}$ such that $y^{m} \rightarrow y$ and $y^{m} \in \Gamma\left(x^{m}\right)$ for each $m$.

Comment: In general to show that $f^{-1}$ is lower hemicontinuous you can show that $f$ is an open mapping; i.e., $f(V)$ is open whenever $O$ is open. See Theorem 17.7 of Aliprantis and Border.

Comment: Thanks David, I will take a look at that reference!

Comment: I notice there is no open mapping theorem for the real space scenario. Do you think I can claim $f$ is an open mapping for the complex plane and invoke lower hemicontinuity? Anything else I need to be worried about?

Comment: Like do we need any surjectivity kind of requirement? It looks like we can always extend X and Y to complex planes and achieve openness?

Comment: I'm confused: why is any extension argument required? Take $Y = \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ and endow it with the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Oh, it's because I'm trying to invoke the open mapping theorem. i.e.,  In complex analysis, the open mapping theorem states that if $U$ is a domain of the complex plane C and $f : U \rightarrow C$ is a non-constant analytic function, then f is an open map. However, this theorem is not valid in real spaces, right?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative definition of upper hemicontinuous: if $ f ^{-1}$ has a closed graph and the images of compact sets in $Y$ are bounded in $X$, $ f ^{-1}$ is UHC (MasCollel, Whinston and Green (1995), Appendix M.H.).

Now, given that you have a finite number of matrix polynomials of some degree (OP didn't specify), boundedness of compact sets should not be an issue.

For the closed graph condition, check all points in $\{ (y,x) \in Y \times X : x \in f^{-1}(y)\}$.

You can do this for all non-measure zero sets to see if those two conditions hold. Seems non-trivial in your case but maybe you can work out the details from here I hope :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that definition. Although I want it to be true for a real domain, it actually occurred to me that because I ended up solving a polynomial system, that should have solutions on the complex plane as well in theory. This gap between application and theory makes me quite frustrated now...But thank you for your answer!@schroederadrian